# FFmpeg: Remux f4v cutted from stream to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, transcoding

I have a mp4 file cutted from a H.264/AAC stream with Wowza Media Server.
After the cutting, the file was forced to mp4 format with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i wowza_output_file -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mp4 -y wowza_output_file_copy
```

From there I renamed it to test_f4v.mp4 and took ffprobe, to take a look at the file:

```
ffprobe version 0.8, Copyright (c) 2007-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 20 2011 13:32:19 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0
  libavformat  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_f4v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : f4v 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42m4v 
    creation_time   : 2012-04-23 12:36:06
  Duration: 01:00:01.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2004 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 854x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 1903 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-23 12:36:06
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-23 12:36:06
```

Now there is a problem. I need a file, which has the following meta data:

```
major_brand     : mp42
compatible_brands: isom
```

Is there a way to remux the mp4 file to get the `major_brand` and `compatible_brands` to the described values with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

You can set arbitrary metadata using the `-metadata` flag for FFmpeg.

From [the man page](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

```
   -metadata[:metadata_specifier] key=value (output,per-metadata)
       Set a metadata key/value pair.

       An optional metadata_specifier may be given to set metadata on
       streams or chapters. See "-map_metadata" documentation for details.

       This option overrides metadata set with "-map_metadata". It is also
       possible to delete metadata by using an empty value.

       For example, for setting the title in the output file:

               ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata title="my title" out.flv

       To set the language of the first audio stream:

               ffmpeg -i INPUT -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng OUTPUT
```

Comment: It don't think, that overwriting the meta data solves the problem. I really need to remux them from f4v to mp4.

Comment: The `major_brand`/`compatible_brands` are distinct from the format, and don't necessarily require transcoding.  See [here](http://www.ftyps.com/what.html) for a description, and note that [`mp42`](http://mp4ra.org/specs.html#MP4V2) and `isom` are very generic as brands go, so the bar isn't high for using them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Wowza formatting, but since you're just copying the actual stream data and only changing the packaging, you could try the [HandBrakeCLI](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) for conversion to mp4.  By default it sets `major_brand` to `mp42` and `compatible_brands` to `mp42isomavc1`.  Perhaps close enough?

Comment: And how to set major brand to mp42 via ffmpeg?